# Mvc OutputCacheLocation.ServerAndClient what exactly does it do?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, outputcache

So i got a ActionResult in my mvc 4 application where i'm fetching a file from a cloud service.
I want to make sure that the file gets cached on the client side so my initial though was to use OutputCacheLocation.Client. 
But i also want to make sure that the user gets a 304 (Not modified request) when refreshing and requesting the file multiple times.

Using ServerAndClient would solve my problem, but how much is being cached on the server? I don't want to cache the entire file (as it could lead to memory issues when it comes to big files).

How does ServerAndClient really work, does it really cache the entire file or just metadata server-side?

Answer (score -1):

Found another way to achieve what i wanted :

http://www.dotnetage.com/Learning/en-US/aspnet-articles/2011/04/02/how-to-cache-files-in-mvc.html